# Is the ending of Fassbinder's "Welt am Draht" (World on a Wire) similar to that of "Simulacron-3", on which it was based?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, world-on-a-wire, simulacron-3

In the seventies Fassbinder made a scifi called "Welt am Draht" (in English "World on a wire"), inspired by "Simulacron-3" by Daniel F. Galouye. I never read the book. If I understood/remember correctly, the hero of the movie discovers at the end that the "real" world to which he managed to ascend is also just a world on a wire.

Does the book have a similar ending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at the end of the book, he transfers to the world higher than his original and that's about that.  Obviously he has no idea if the world he just entered is the top or not, but this is never addressed as it seems to no longer be that important.  His girlfriend could love him though he was a simulation and the whole "I think, therefore I am" concept seems to gain full importance in his mind.