# German tv-seriers about paranoid man believing he is not in the real world

Tags: story-identification

This is a tv-series made in the 70's in West Germany.

The plot is a man that senses that everything is not as it seems, he feels like everything is a computer simulation. There are people after him trying to prevent him from discovering the truth. A woman is helping him.

Spoiler tags might not be needed but the ending is:

> It turns out he is right. His mind has been projected into a simulation while
>  he is beeing cured of a disease. They try to prevent him of discovering the
>  truth to prevent his mind from harming itself.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83562 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/36431

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds very much like *[Welt am Draht](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070904)* (*World on a Wire*) (1973), directed by Rainer Werner Fassbinder and starring Klaus Löwitsch in the lead role.  It is based on the novel *[Simulacron-3](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7607)* (1964) by Daniel F. Galouye.  The same book was filmed again as *[The Thirteenth Floor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139809)* (1999).

*Welt am Draht* was however not a series, but a two part made-for-TV film, at least in the version I saw. IMDB agrees with this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for helping me out on this one.